# g++ not suppressing warnings

Tags: c++, g++, deprecation-warning

I am facing the weirdest thing ever. I am having a deprecation warning although I am using `-Wno-deprecated` flag with `g++`.

What am I doing wrong? Should I reorder the flags I am passing to `g++`?

```
g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -D__LINUX__ -DOS_USE_STD_IOSTREAMS -DOS_LINUX_2_2 -D__CPP -D__USE_BSD -DLINUX -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused -DOS_USE_STD_IOSTREAM -m64 -m64 -O3 -Werror
```

The deprecation warning is specifically about `sys_errlist` and that I should use `stderror` or `stderror_r`.

I have checked the specific header file declraing the function that uses `sys_errlist` and it doesn't have a diagnostic pragma.

I am using `GCC 3.3.1` on a `64` bit `RHE4` machine

Comment: But why don't you use `strerror`? I don't see any reason to use `sys_errlist` on Linux (or BSD)

Comment: Perhaps the header overrides the warning option with [diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Comment: It's not code that I am allowed to modify and I should use it as a black-box. What you are saying is 100% valid but is not targeting my issue.

Comment: @user2079303 Oh well, nice point I'll check that.

Comment: @user2079303 No this isn't the case. There are no pragmas at all.